# Mocked Service in a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

The idea is to mock the service based on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/alicial/7681791). Where the service is **redefined** and then the injection happens, the **new overwritten service** is used by the directive/controller.

How it's possible to inject the overwritten on the directive? The following snippet shows how it's inserted on the controller:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _UserService_) { // inject mocked service
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('MyController', {
        $scope: scope,
        UserService: _UserService_
    });

}));
```